# How the priority will be given in PriorityQueue when some random elements are added?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

when I add some random numbers in a PriorityQueue, when I print the PriorityQueue the elements are printed in different order.

how it is happening?

example

```
    PriorityQueue<Integer> s=new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
            s.add(22);
            s.add(212);
            s.add(423);
            s.add(323);
            s.add(1);
            System.out.print(s);

output:
    [1, 22, 423, 323, 212]
```

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` returns a representation of the internal storage of the priority queue, not of the logical order of the elements. The same is true for `toArray()` and for iteration: none of these methods guarantee that the elements will be returned in their order of priority.

If you want to obtain the elements in the order of priority, you need to `poll()` them individually (and thus destroy the queue). `PriorityQueue` is thus not a suitable data structure if you want to list the elements in a particular order. A `SortedSet` would be more appropriate here. By contrast, queue data structures (of which `PriorityQueue` is a special case) are used for receiving and retrieving elements once, not for inspecting data at rest.

Answer (score 2):

It has no guaranteed order (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` and the `Spliterator` provided in method `spliterator()` are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

Normally you retrieve elements according to their natural order using the `poll()` method, for example:

```
 while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
     var element = pq.poll();
     ...
 }
```